# Getting error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'. when convert mysql query to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I am converting mysql to sql query, i did many changes for that to run query in sql server, but still i am getting error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.`, can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ? Here is my query for that

```
UPDATE tb_EpVisitRange as v 
left JOIN tb_Episode as e 
  ON v.BranchID   = e.BranchID 
 AND v.company_id = e.CustID 
 AND v.CMW        = e.CMW
SET
e.EpVisitCount = IIF(PayerType = 'NonEp', 0, IIF(LUPA = 1, 0, v.High)),
e.VisitAlert = IIF(Status = 'Closed', 0, IIF((IIF(PayerType = 'NonEp', 0, IIF(LUPA = 1, 0, v.High))) > 0, 1, 0))
where  billed_flag = '0';
```

Comment: You're trying to update the table on the left side of the join here. What are you expecting to do if a record isn't found..?

Comment: This actually works on MySql? If so, this is one more reason to not work with MySql. The more I learn about it, the more I don't like it.

Comment: The update is on v but the set is on e.  It has other problems also.  Update a left join make zero sense here.  If the record does not exists there is nothing to update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting error incorrect syntax near the keyword as in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584203/getting-error-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-as-in-sql-server)

Comment: Same exact question as [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584203/getting-error-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-as-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax in SQL Server is:

```
UPDATE e
    SET EpVisitCount = (CASE WHEN PayerType = 'NonEp' THEN 0
                             WHEN LUPA = 1 THEN 0
                             ELSE v.High
                        END),
        VisitAlert = (CASE WHEN Status = 'Closed' THEN 0
                           WHEN PayerType = 'NonEp' THEN 0
                           WHEN LUPA = 1 THEN 0
                           WHEN v.High > 0 THEN 1
                           ELSE 0
                      END)
    FROM tb_EpVisitRange v JOIN
         tb_Episode e
         ON v.BranchID = e.BranchID AND v.company_id = e.CustID AND v.CMW = e.CMW
    WHERE billed_flag = 0;
```

Notes:

- Learn proper SQL Server syntax if you are going to use the database.
- Use `CASE`; it is proper SQL and works in all proper databases.  This is especially true if you have multiple conditions.
- If you are updating `e`, then you want an `INNER JOIN` or to make `e` the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.  Updating an unmatched row makes no sense.
- `billed_flag` is, presumably, a number so don't use quotes around the comparison value.